# Calculated Field Causing Duplicates in Another Query Field

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, calculated-field

I have created a calculated filed inside of a MS Access DB. This field is designed to divide the "Build Rate" by the "Adjust Total". The problem when I run the query is, that it makes duplicates in the "LS_Name" field. I believe there to something wrong with my syntax; please help. Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Claims.LS_Name, Suppliers.QE, Suppliers.Group, 
    [Issue Bucket].Status, [Issue Bucket].[Total $], Claims.[Total(Total)], 
    Claims.Debited, Year([Jdg_date]) & Month([Jdg_date]) AS PayDate, 
    Claims.Hour_Meter, Claims.Line_off_Date, 
    Month([Line_off_Date]) & "/1/" & Year([Line_off_Date]) 
        AS [CDate(«expression») «Expr» LOD], 
    [Adjust(Total)]/([Build Rate]![(Total]) AS WCPperUnit
FROM [Build Rate], Suppliers 
   INNER JOIN ([Issue Bucket] 
       INNER JOIN Claims ON [Issue Bucket].[Issue Bucket] = Claims.[Issue Description]) 
   ON (Suppliers.Supplier = Claims.LS_Name) 
   AND (Suppliers.[Supplier Code] = [Issue Bucket].LS_Name)
WHERE (((Claims.Debited)=False));
```

Comment: The query does not include a `JOIN` for `[Build Rate]`.  So you have an implicit [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_join#Cross_join) which may be the cause of the duplicates.

Comment: I believe I see the problem; thank you very much!